# Mono for WinRT Desktop?

Tags: arm, mono-framework

Can mono runtime install on SurfaceRT?

I want to user mono to create .net program run on it.

Is there any windows arm version of mono?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows RT (what the Surface RT runs) does [not support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_RT#Software_compatibility) traditional applications, otherwise known as "win32" applications.  As Mono is a win32 application it cannot run on a Surface RT.  The Surface RT is also "[locked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_RT#Restrictions_and_compatibility_limitations)" so you cannot install your own applications - even IF they were recompiled for the ARM processor.

Comment: I can run .net 4.0 or 4.5 desktop app on Surface RT when it was jailbreak. But Windows RT not support WPF apps. WinForm UI is very stupid. So I want to use gtk# on Surface Rt but I can not find any ARM version of it...

Comment: You can't find it because it doesn't exist.  The above is your answer: the RT versions of Windows are locked-down and closed ecosystems.  Jailbreaking let's you get a bit more but not enough for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

here you find supported platforms
http://www.mono-project.com/Supported_Platforms
but http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:ARM